# I am getting an error in taking remainder of range ?why is this happening

Tags: python, python-3.x, range, fizzbuzz

```
n = int(input())

for x in (range(1,n))%2!=0:

    if x % 3 == 0 and x % 5 == 0:
        print("SoloLearn")
    elif x % 3 == 0:
        print("Solo")
    elif x % 5 == 0:
        print("Learn")
```

It gives this error---TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'range' and 'int'
why can i not divide 2 by range of numbers?

Comment: *for x in (range(1,n))%2!=0*?

Comment: If you want the odd numbers, `for x in (range(1, n, 2)` would do it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. In your own words, *what do you expect this code to mean*? Why do you think you *should* be able to "divide 2 by a range of numbers" (it appears that you actually mean "divide a range of numbers by 2")? What do you think should be the result when you do that? Why?

Comment: Should it also be possible to do this kind of math with other things? Why? Which kinds of things? According to what logic?

Comment: @user1740577 - because (1) I wrote it as you posted and (2) its not really an answer to the question " why can i not divide 2 by range of numbers?" but a guess about the intent of the for loop.

Answer (score 1):

you want odd numbers try this:

```
for x in (range(1,n,2)):
```

instead of:

```
for x in (range(1,n))%2!=0:
```

Comment: Giving just code is not a good way to tell OP want went wrong. Please elaborate

Comment: Why is ```for x in (range(1,n))%2!=0:``` wrong? By the way, I didn't down vote.

Comment: @Sujay i write that OP you want odd number can try this answer

Comment: But you need to explain what is wrong (if possible), just giving the right answer is not enough. SO is not a code-writing service. You need to show where they are wrong (and provide a better alternative), so that they can learn.

Answer (score 0):

Python objects decide for themselves what operations mean by implementing magic methods - see [Emulating Numeric Types](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-numeric-types). `range(1,n) % 2` translates to calling `range(1,n).__mod__`. But that method isn't implemented for `range` objects because the authors didn't think it made sense to modulo an integer generator. Remember, this is an operation on the generator object, not the integers iterated by the generator.

If you really wanted to divide a range of numbers by 2, you could do it as the numbers are generated

```
>>> for x in (y % 2 for y in range(10)):
...     print(x)
```

Answer (score -1):

Are you trying to create a list of odd numbers?
YOu could try:

```
for x in [num for num in range(1,n) if num x%2]:
    #do_stuff
```

note that you can lose the !=0 part of the check because non-zero integers equate to True

As noted by Sujay, there's a quicker way to do it that hides the underlying mechanism.
The example I gave you can be modified to use more complex checks.

ALSO!
Note that you don't really want to do this. You're solving fizzbuzz, you need to iterate over all numbers. Number 30 is even and you want to print 'sololearn' ('fizzbuzz') when you reach it.

Comment: When you can just do ```range(1,n,2)```, why to create a new list?

Comment: Just to illustrate the underlying mechanism. Adding the step to range is, of course, a smoother way to do it